# Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart

При запуске приложения (первый запуск) выходит такая ошибка. Код сгенерированный программой так что он наверняка правильный. Запускаюсь НЕ через виртуальный андроид, а через собственный телефон (У меня произошли какие-то траблы с этим так как у меня видеокарта и процессор АМД) Мне показался этот путь самым простым. Ну он и правда был очень прост. В общем помогите убрать эту ошибку. Вот полный код ошибки:

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.

 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
 Required by:
     project :
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: попробуйте обновить градл до последней версии

Comment: Не сработало...

Comment: все со всем разобрался. Нужно изменить compileSdkVersion 28 на compileSdkVersion 29. Вроде все заработало.